# Closing StreamSource

Tags: java, xslt, java-ws

I was getting a too many open files error on my web service and just wanted to make sure that there's nothing else that I have to close.  I added a `close()` on `outWriter` (`StringWriter`), but the JavaDoc said that this has no effect. `getCachedExtractSoapBodyXslt()` gets the `javax.xml.transform.Transformer` object.

```
String payload;
StreamResult result=null;
StringWriter outWriter=null;
try {
    // Programmatically extract the SOAP Body from message
    outWriter = new StringWriter();
    result = new StreamResult(outWriter);
    Source src = new StreamSource(new java.io.StringReader(doc));
    getCachedExtractSoapBodyXslt().transform(src, result);
    StringBuffer sb = outWriter.getBuffer();
    payload = sb.toString();
} catch (TransformerException e) {
    throw new ComponentException("Unable to extract SOAP Body");
}
finally {
    LOG.debug("Closing XSLT transformer output stream");
    try {
        outWriter.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        LOG.error("Failed to close stream for SOAP message");
    }
}
```

Comment: The [documentation for StringWriter.close()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/StringWriter.html#close--) states that it has no effect.  The documentation for StringReader.close() doesn't say anything beyond what Reader.close() says, but it seems unlikely that either StringReader nor StringWriter makes use of sockets.

Comment: @VGR, Oops I meant too many open files, not sockets.  I've updated the question.

Comment: StringReader and StringWriter don't use files either, I'm pretty sure.  It might help to change all use of InputStreams, OutputStreams and Channels in your program to make use of [try-with-resources statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) so there's no chance that any are being left unclosed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to move this to it's own variable and to close it

```
new java.io.StringReader(doc)
```

Answer (score 0):

StreamSource has no close, and what I've observed the users of it don't close the stream or reader it holds. And try-with-resource isn't an option either since it's not "closeable". So had to go old school and use a try/finally that called it's getInputStream and GetReader methods and pass their result to IOUtils.closeQuietly

```
StreamSource source = null;
try {
   source = new StreamSource(inputStream);
   // Do stuff with source
}
finally {
   IOUtils.closeQuietly(source.getInputStream());
}
```

In my case I actually had to call both getInputStream and getReader since my source was constructed in two different ways.